# Unfixed Responsive design styling

Tags: css, image, alignment, href, src

> **Updated!!!**

I've still facing the same error each time I view the page on landscape screen devices.

CSS:

```
f5 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

about.us

```
<div class="containerpreview">
    <br>
         <f5>Check out our products</f5>
    <br>
         <f6>and Experience no-frills delivery</f6>
    <div style="margin-top:40px">
        <div class="buttoneshop"><a href="...">Eshop</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is there a way to make the spacing in between closer? When I command out

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

the spacing is fine.

[image]

Aside of that, is there a way to make an image inside src under href to be centered?

[image]

**css**

```
.images_1_of_4 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    <!-- height: 200px; -->
    width: 200px;
    align: middle;
}

.img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }
.grid_preview {
    height: 200px;
}
```

**shop.php**

```
<div class="grid_1_of_4 images_1_of_4">
    <div class="grid_preview">
        <a href="..."><img src="..." alt=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably have this set `text-align: justify;` set it to `text-align: left;`

Comment: Good catch, @Vallentin

Comment: not working. Actually i forgot to add. It's not working when i rwd it @Vallentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change alignment `text-align : justify;` to `text-align : left`.

Or, if this is not what you like to do, [letter-spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp) is a CSS attibute to change space between charagcters, and [word-spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp) to change space between words

Comment: not working. Actually i forgot to add. It's not working when i rwd it

Answer (score 1):

As other users suggested, consider forcing alignment on the left using `text-align : left`, you probably have `text-align : justify;` on a wrapper element or setted in another part of your css as depicted the example below.

https://jsfiddle.net/s5p9872t/

```
.f5 {
   text-align : justify;
    width: 250px;
}

.f5 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: not working. Actually i forgot to add. It's not working when i rwd it